# vaadin TwinColSelect not side by side

Tags: vaadin7

For some reason my TwinColSelect is not side by side.  See below:
[image]

Has anybody seen this before?  I have tried putting it into a HorizontalLayout, etc.

Edit:  Here is a better example:
[image]

It is in a FormLayout, which is inside a Panel, if that helps.  This matches some examples I have seen online.

Edit 2: Overall structure ( mimics Dashboard demo app!!! ):

```
MainView - HorizontalLayout
    Menu component
    Content component ( VerticalSplitPanel )
        Header - HorizontalLayout
        Content, where things really go ( CssLayout )
            UsersView ( VerticalLayout )
                 User Header ( HorizontalLayout )
                 User list ( Table )
                 UserForm ( Panel )
                     form ( FormLayout )
                         Various data entry fields ( TextField, ComboBox, etc )
                         notifications selection ( TwinColSelect )
                         save button ( Button )
```

Edit 3: As stated in the comments, the captions are perfectly positioned.  The elements that are broken are the UI elements that allow user interaction, the arrow buttons and the right selection box.  So another way to ask this question is:  What controls the position of the arrows and the right selection box?  Because whatever controls that position is messed up.  If I just knew where to look, I could probably figure it out, but I don't know where to start.

Incidentally, I did try setting the width various components to 100%, which also did not work.

If I have to, I will add a button to "show notifications", which will popup a PopupView with this TwinColSelect, letting users do what they need to do there.  But I really want to avoid that as it is not user friendly.

Update 4/27/2016:
Ok, based on the comments, I can see that setting "?theme=valo" makes it work.  Since I started my application with the dashboard demo as my starting point, and since the dashboard uses some version of the dashboard theme already ( dashboard.scss includes "../valo/valo" ), it seems our customized version of the valo theme somehow messes up the TwinColSelect.  I say "our customized version of the valo theme" because I literally just added duplicates of scss and css that already existed, I did not really make changes to those files.  So my next step is to look at those customized scss files, or put the TwinColSelect into my local dashboard demo ( I was using it to play with features before adding it to my application ).  Obviously, if anyone can point me to a possible scss that could cause this type of problem, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide code for a SSCCE. What happens if you temporarily change the layout to VerticalLayout or similar?

Comment: I don't have a short and simple example.  I did try putting putting it into a VerticalLayout, but that did not work.  Not that there is much conceptual difference between a VerticalLayout and a FormLayout:  both are vertical and both are ordered, just FormLayout puts captions to the left.

Comment: Note that the captions are perfect: overall caption "Notification Groups" is to the left, as defined by FormLayout.  The left caption "Available notifications" is over the left selection box, as expected.  The right caption "Selected notifications" is over where the right selection box should be.

Comment: Changing "FormLayout" to "VerticalLayout" did not help.

Comment: It often helps to make a SSCCE not only for the community to provide an answer but also for yourself to find an error (if the problem is with your code and not in Vaadin).

Comment: I would think the structure I defined in one of my edits to be more then sufficient to, at the very least, point me in the right direction.  Also, as I pointed out, the captions are perfect.  If the captions were wrong as well, it would actually make more sense to me, suggesting some layouting or container issue.  But that is not the case.  All this is indicative of something, I just don't know where to look for that "something", thus my questions here.  I understand your point, and will try to come up with something, but so far I have bigger problems to solve.

Comment: Are you sure it is not theme related? Have you modified the css? Try adding to the end of the url ?theme=valo. Whole url would look something like localhost:8080/yourapp?theme=valo

Comment: No major updates to CSS.  I started with the demo dashboard app, so it should be the valo theme ( knock on wood ).  I basically just copied one of those CSS for my new views, just as placeholders for future CSS enhancements I might need to do for the views in question.  That said, definitely worth a try.  Will get back to you.

Comment: Another try is to re-compile your widget set.

Comment: Ok, theme=valo actually does change things considerably, including making the TwinColSelect work better.  So I guess the demo dashboard app actually does change quite a few items from the default valo theme.  So I guess this suggests a problem with one of my custom CSS?

Comment: Also, a Vaadin contact suggested looking more closely at the "?debug" for layout problems.  Since I have not fully mastered that tool, sort of forgot it.  So now I have two things to check: custom CSS and "?debug".  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem ended up being in the main theme scss. So my theme scss, mobiwms.scss, was copied verbatim from the demo dashboard.scss, which has the following lines:

```
// Optimize the CSS output
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, accordion);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, colorpicker);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, grid);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, popupview);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, progressbar);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, slider);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, splitpanel);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, tree);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, treetable);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, twincolselect);
```

The key was to comment out or remove the "remove" statements that were invalid now ( because I actually do use the components that the above code "removes" theme information for ).  So I simply changed the above to the below and it worked:

```
// Optimize the CSS output
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, accordion);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, colorpicker);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, grid);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, popupview);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, progressbar);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, slider);
// $v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, splitpanel);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, tree);
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, treetable);
// $v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, twincolselect);
```

I knew it was something like this, just did not know the right question to ask.  Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
VerticalLayout pageLayout = new VerticalLayout();

FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
pageLayout.addComponent(formLayout);

TwinColSelect twinSelect = new TwinColSelect("Twin");
formLayout.addComponent(twinSelect);
```

The above code working for me, try this.

Comment: As you can see from the structure of my app in my original post, I already am sort of doing what you describe.  Your example is much simpler then mine, of course, but mine also has a FormLayout inside a VerticalLayout.  That said, your suggestion might come in handy when I finally have time to try it in the dashboard demo.